# Customizing tabs on state in Android

Tags: android, tabs, selector, drawable

I know how to put the icon on each tab, that is no problem. I also ran across this :
[Stack Overflow thread on pretty much same thing][1]

I followed one of the links from that question and found [this][2]

Pretty much, it said to use a selector defined in the XML, sure, did that. But there is no id associated w/ it so I am not sure how to get the selector function as a drawable so I can use it as the icon for the tabs. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way. But this is what I have, and obviously missing something.

```
<selector
    android:id="@+id/myselector"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/darklogo" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />
</selector>
```

In my code, an example tab is generated using :

```
  host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("three")  
                .setIndicator("map",drawables)  
                .setContent(new Intent(this, Map.class)));
```

Right now drawable is just a reference to a drawable image resource. How do I make the selector a drawable?

This is my question  [1]: [Updating Android Tab Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881/updating-android-tab-icons) [2]: http://groups.google.com/group/android-evelopers/browse_thread/thread/ef3bdebcb715b385

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The XML you've included here is a way of defining a drawable that lets you embed a case statement. It presents a different drawable depending on the state of the View it's being assigned to. As a drawable, you should save it as an xml file within the `res/drawable` folder of your project (for example `tabselector.xml`).

To use it for the Tabhost, you need to construct the TabActivity as you normally would (as shown in this [tutorial example](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)).

Then when you add each tab to the host, you specify the `tabselector` drawable as the indicator as shown for "TAB 1" below.

```
Drawable mySelector = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabselector);

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1", mySelector).setContent(R.id.textview1));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
```

Note: You *cannot* change the color of the tab backgrounds behind the icons at this point.

Comment: As usual. Thank you very much. I think not having it my my drawable folder was my bigger issue. Thank you for including some code to get me moving.. I appreciate it.

Comment: is this possible now? i mean your Note statement. check my question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810075/customizing-tab-indicator-images-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You could use a View as an indicator, this way you can customize it the way you wish.

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator(View MyView).setContent(R.id.textview1));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
```

The first tab will use a View as its indicator and the second a CharSequence. Have a look at the actual TabSpec class (**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html**).