# Customizing tab indicator images in android?

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

how to change the tab indicator's images in android? there is a [tab_indicator.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/res/res/drawable/tab_indicator.xml;hb=HEAD) file in-built in android sdk. in that the [Relative layout has the background as a tab_indicator](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/res/res/layout/tab_indicator.xml;hb=HEAD) file as background. how to customize this images in tab_indicator and set our new images? I have a problem that the not selected tabs are highlighted with a white under line.because of those images. how to customize it?

That RelativeLayout doesn't have the id to access.how can i?Any Idea? Please help.

Note: [Reto Meier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773690/android-customizing-tabs-on-state-how-do-i-make-a-selector-a-drawable/779588#779588) a year ago says. its not possible at that time. what about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that i 100% understand the problem. If you want custom view as your tab indicator there is API for that
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator(android.view.View)

Comment: i cant customize the style of the tabs. check the Note in my question please.

Comment: From 1.6 you can provide a custom view to setIndicator

Comment: Thanks for reply. May you give sample code snippet for that View. it will be More understandable. :)

Comment: I will tonight, but basically - define layout, inflate it. Set it as indicator. Look at foursquare project ( it's open source ) - UserDetailsActivity should have an example of what you're looking for.