# Remove the bottom line border in tab bar? (And change selected color)

Tags: android, user-interface

Is it possible to remove the bottom line showed in the tab bar? It is grey when not selected.

And is it possible to change the yellowish color to something else?

[image]

layout xml: http://pastebin.com/M2KqtH1r

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:theme="@style/tabTheme"/>
```

In values/styles.xml:

```
 <style name="tabTheme" parent="android:style/Theme"> 
      <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/Widget.TabWidget</item>
 </style> 

 <style name="Widget.TabWidget" parent="android:Theme"> 
      <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition, Could be good to know that the option "tabStripEnabled" was introduced in Android 2.2 i.e API Level 8. And for older API there is a workaround here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164325/tabstripenabled-for-tabwidget-in-older-apis

Answer (score 39):

just do this in your tabWidget in your xml file.

```
android:tabStripEnabled="false"
```

hope you get it. ;)

Comment: that should be accepted as the right answer as it is the easy way to do so. While doing like Good Guy Greg's answer remove my tab icon also.

Comment: It is perfect. To enable in java,   tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);

Answer (score 15):

**android:tabStripEnabled="false" didnt work for me**
By doing the following i was able to get it working

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
```

These 2 are the main things

```
 app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: this is correct for TabLayout. Accepted answer works for TabWidget

Answer (score 2):

You have customize your tab indicator. That is to overriding your tabwidget style. I had this problem already. Check these two posts: [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804688/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-tabs-indicator-text-in-android) and [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810075/customizing-tab-indicator-images-in-android).

Comment: So basically I have to copy these current tab images, add them with setIndicator and then the selector line will not appear?

Comment: Hmm Is it possible to extract Android default tab images?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved it by:

```
android:alpha="0"
```

Here the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
            android:alpha="0"
            style="@style/TabStyle" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the way of doing that is to nest the tabwidget in a LinerLayout... Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245382/how-to-get-rid-of-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-tabhost).

Comment: I was hoping that would work, but it didn't.  The guy seem to be running 1.5 but I am running 2.2. However I have updated my post with my layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling that line below use tab:

```
app:tabIndicator="@null"
```