# How to remove bottom line of custom Tab view

Tags: android

[image]

How can I remove that line from my tab view? Or can I set height or colors for it?

Comment: Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543478/remove-the-bottom-line-border-in-tab-bar-and-change-selected-color

Comment: I have checked it. Problem is going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try defining a new theme with windowContentOverlay set to null:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And then apply this theme to your activity in your manifest (or you can apply it to the  element to apply it application-wide):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stylingandroid.VectorDrawables" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

That should remove the shadow.

If you want to change the colour of it set android:cacheColorHint in the style.

Comment: Where sholud I use android:cacheColorHint ? Can you give me example please.

Comment: And one more thing, a gray background displaying in bottom of deselected tabs how can change or remove it?

Comment: Use <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item> (or another colour if you want to actually see it) in the style in the same way as the android:windowContentOverlay item.

Comment: Your question about the grey background may be better asked as a separate question. Also, provide a screen shot similar to the one in this question so that it's claer precisely what you're referring to.