# How to remove the line for bottom tabs in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android. I have created the bottom tabs for my project and it is working fine. But my question is to how to remove the line at the bottom? I have kept the following line 
      **android:tabStripEnabled="true"** in my layout.

The line is removed but when i am clicking the individual tabs a small line on both the sides of individual tab is existing. Can anybody suggest how to remove that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost().setTabStripEnabled(false);
```

The previous answer might not be working on emulator but it must work on a phone. Have tried it on a real device?

Answer (score 1):

```
  tabStripEnabled = false
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543478/remove-the-bottom-line-border-in-tab-bar-and-change-selected-color) is answer of your question.

Comment: Thanks for response. But if I kept that the line remains as it is. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

If u are using `TabLayout` in android Just Remove

```
 android:elevation="@dimen/_1sdp"
```

this line.
Hope THis help someone!