# TabWidget current tab bottom line color

Tags: android, android-tabs

I have a TabWidget for which I have enabled and set the `stripLeft` and `stripRight`...

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(R.drawable.redline);
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(R.drawable.redline);
```

As you can see in the image below, this does not change the bottom line color of the currently selected tab (TAB 2).

[image]

How can I change the bottom line color of the currently selected tab which is defaulted to blue at the moment? (I am guessing the blue color is being set in the default `AppTheme` style in `styles.xml`.)

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543478/remove-the-bottom-line-border-in-tab-bar-and-change-selected-color) answer but it does not say how to change the color...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The color of the tab indicator is being set by a selector drawable which can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/tab_indicator_holo.xml) and looks like this:

```
<!-- AOSP copyright notice can be found at the above link -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

The drawables that the selector uses are all colored in that light blue.  You can replace those drawables with your own recolored versions.  The originals look like this (originals are small, links included):

- [tab_unselected_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_holo.9.png) [image: tab_unselected_holo]
- [tab_selected_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_selected_holo.9.png) [image: tab_selected_holo]
- [tab_unselected_focused_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_focused_holo.9.png) [image: tab_unselected_focused_holo]
- [tab_selected_focused_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_selected_focused_holo.9.png) [image: tab_selected_focused_holo]
- [tab_unselected_pressed_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png) [image: tab_unselected_pressed_holo]
- [tab_selected_pressed_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_selected_pressed_holo.9.png) [image: tab_selected_pressed_holo]

You'll want to copy the above selector into your own project along with the drawables.  Then you'll want to recolor the drawables to whatever color you want them to be. Then you'll want to set your selector as the background for your tab indicators.  You can do that like this (after setting up your tabs):

```
TabHost host = (TabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
TabWidget widget = host.getTabWidget();
for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = widget.getChildAt(i);

    // Look for the title view to ensure this is an indicator and not a divider.
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if(tv == null) {
        continue;
    }
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_tab_selector_drawable);
}
```

There might be an easier way to do this by setting your own customer indicator layout with a background selector but this is what worked easiest for me.

Comment: Hey @MCeley thanks for your answer man. I'm trying to get this work too right now and pertaining to the tab_unselected_holo, tab_selected_holo etc they are all pngs so to replace them I'll have to like make my own with different colors, but I don't know the size of the default pngs and I don't know if it work well.

Comment: Just download the images that are linked in my post and make them match those sizes.

Comment: Rolled back the answer to what it was originally.  While http://android-holo-colors.com/ is a useful site for creating entire themes that will also change the tab colors, this question wasn't about creating a theme.

Comment: Can you do this without drawables, but with colors instead? I feel like that way it would be much easier to edit the theme if I wanted, or am I missing something?

Comment: this is crazy, it's just freakin' color of indicator and so much work

Comment: Thanks. I'm following [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=bar&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=1&hairline=0&neutralPressed=0&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=fff%2C100&tabColor=ffc800%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) to have image. In app I'm using **Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen** and this not allowing me to use **Yellow** color at tab-bottom. It display light-blue only. Any suggestion!

Comment: Sorry @Shubh but I don't have anything off the top of my head. I would recommend posting this as a separate question and seeing if somebody can help you with it.

Comment: Google knows hot to implement simple things difficult

Comment: How do you show the indicator to the top (instead of the bottom)?

Comment: You'd likely have to make a new layout for each of the tab widget items. You could likely do this through theming but there are several different approaches that could work. It's a bit outside the scope of this question/answer though so I'd recommend posting a new question to get more detailed answers.

Comment: Why can't we simply use the following attribute to change the color of the selection indicator? `app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/theme_color"`.

Comment: @RahulRaveendran This question/answer was written before the design support library was around and added that functionality to the platform. I would suggest writing an answer that outlined how to use the design library tabs and setting the color the easy way as that would be a more appropriate and modern way of doing things.

Answer (score 26):

You can use **app:tabIndicatorColor** for this purpose. It will change the selected tab indicator line color according to your requirement.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Comment: I think he's using TabHost and TabWidget, not TabLayout.

Answer (score 12):

This is how I changed my tabs,

```
private void changetabs(TabWidget tabWidget) {
    // Change background
    for(int i=0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++)
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
}
```

and my tab_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
```

Hope it will help some one.

Comment: When will 'changetabs' be called ??

Answer (score 10):

Incase some one stumbles on it, There is online tool to quickly build the drawables (9 patch) for the tabs. Just select the color and press the button Here you go ...

Thanks to Jeff Gilfelt

---

The Android Action Bar Style Generator allows you to easily create a simple, attractive and seamless custom action bar style for your Android application. It will generate all necessary nine patch assets plus associated XML drawables and styles which you can copy straight into your project.

### http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to do this. THANK YOU JEFF! :D

Comment: Great! Really an easy way to change tabwidget bottom line color.

Comment: Tried to use this but it doesn't change the tab colors, only the tab bar colors; any suggestions?

Comment: Yah, I tired to add it but it only changes the Tab Indicator colors, not tab bar and tab indicator colors (tab bar color just defaults to transparent)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a filter,
This will be applied to the region that isn't transparent

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

One line of code - no need to change states.

Comment: So Good , But How Change TextColor ? Ater setIndicator("TAB_A")

Comment: You just saved my day. I don't get why this isn't marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

Accent color is used by default as active tab color.
You can set/change it in `style.xml` file:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Really simple and no need to add any extra XMLs

Answer (score 2):

My way to solve this problem is using setBackgroundResource.
First, you have to create the exactly same backgroud

line_label_1_pressed.xml

```
<item android:top="-6dp" android:left="-6dp" android:right="-6dp">
    <shape>
        <size android:height="50dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/myColor" android:width="6dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

line_label_1.xml

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and then create tab_selector.xml as follow

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/line_label_1_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/line_label_1"/>
```

then setbackgroudResource using tab_selector.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution, open *styles.xml* and change one line:

res -> values -> styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item> <!-- set the color in this line -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use something like

```
tabHost.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
```