# Trying to change the blue line color of the tabawidget

Tags: android, android-layout

So I just want to change the blue line color of tab widget in the app. I searched online and the found solutions to changing the whole background of the tabs but i just want to change the blue line color of the tab widget to another color like black.  Can that be done?

[image: the blue lines]

Comment: possible duplicate of [TabWidget current tab bottom line color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this style:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_selected="false"
            android:state_pressed="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_selected="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_selected="false"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_selected="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_selected="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_selected="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_selected="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_selected="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

</selector>
```

You can visit [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color) also.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help @Rushabh Patel but I can't find this file in the res folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate Style for your tabwidget in your custom theme.

Try out as below:

```
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@android:style/Widget.TabWidget</item>
```

and

```
<style name="Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>  


<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/tab_indicator_text</item>
</style>
```

I hope this will be helpfull to you.