# TabWidget changr bottom line color

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

i want to change color of tabwidget background. [image] How can i change color of blue line??

My code is:

```
public class MainActivityNew extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private int oldButtonId = 1;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private Database db;
private FrameLayout frame;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Новости", "Мои купоны"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

}

private void initialization() {
    frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), actionBar, frame, viewPager);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.content_frame);

    ///////////////Add now 16/01/2014
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.color.tabTransparent);

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_new,mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.news_icon_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("1")
            .setIndicator(tabIndicator),
            FragmentNews.class, b);


    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_new,mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.catalog_icon_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("2")
            .setIndicator(tabIndicator), FragmentCatalog.class, b);


    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_center,mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_cards_icon_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("3").
            setIndicator(tabIndicator),FragmentMyCards.class, b);

    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_new,mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.near_icon_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("4").
            setIndicator(tabIndicator),FragmentNear.class, b);

    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator_new,mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings_icon_selector));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("5").
            setIndicator(tabIndicator), FragmentSettingsPartOne.class, b);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            setActivityView(Integer.valueOf(tabId));
            Log.d("tabs", "tabID=" + tabId);
        }
    });
    ////////////////////end of adding
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));

    }
    setButtonsColor(1, 3);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

public void setActivityView(int newButtonId) {

    switch (newButtonId) {
        case 1:
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            actionBar.show();
            viewPager.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 8.0f));
            frame.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 0f));
            break;
        default:
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            actionBar.hide();
            frame.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 8.0f));
            viewPager.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 0f));

            break;
    }




}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    initialization();
    db = Database.getInstance(this);


    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */

     viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
    super.onResume();    /
}
}
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color) i try next

```
 TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
    for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = widget.getChildAt(i);

        // Look for the title view to ensure this is an indicator and not a divider.
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        if(tv == null) {
            continue;
        }
      //  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_tab_selector_drawable);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

But it only change background color of bottom tabs.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use android.support.design.widget.TabLayout instead

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/actionbar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator_color" // this is what you want
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"  // tab indicator height
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/font_color_white70"/>
```

This has backward compatibility also