# TabHost indicator color change code not working

Tags: android, indicator, fragment-tab-host

I have been reading on Stack to try to change my color of the indicator (the underline of the tab that tells you which tab is selected), but I used code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color), but it won't work. I get 2 errors:

1. In `view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost)`, the view and the tabhost are red (cannot resolve symbol).
2. One is at `widget.getChildCount()`, it says the method invocation may produce a null pointer exception.
3. Third error is at `v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector_color);` it says the same, it may produce a null pointer exception.

I downloaded all the drawables and changed their color like the above link said, then I put them all in my drawable-mdpi folder, just as it suggested.

I will post a section of my main activity, which has this the code block with errors in it, and also the `tab_selector_color.xml`, which is in my drawable folder (i think it must be put here, instead of layout folder, since it has `selector` tags).

How to fix these errors? Thanks in advance, please let me know if anything is not clear or if you need to see more files.

**Method with the errors from my main activity:**

(I took our the title code below,  because I don't have a `TextView` anywhere (using icons for my indicator drawable part), but whether that code is there or not, the 3 errors are still there).

```
public void changeTabIndicators() {
        FragmentTabHost host = (FragmentTabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        TabWidget widget = host.getTabWidget();
        for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = widget.getChildAt(i);

//            // Look for the title view to ensure this is an indicator and not a divider.
//            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
//            if(tv == null) {
//                continue;
//            }
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector_color);
        }
    }
```

**tab_selector_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the yellow warnings (errors on # 2 and 3) did not cause problems, but what I did change was the `.getChildCount()` method. I looked it up in the [TabWidget Android pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) and could not find this method there, so I used `getTabCount()` instead. To fix the error in the word `view` from `view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost)`, I deleted out `view.` and that fixed it.

I also deleted the TextView code, because my tabs are not using text, but rather icons in the little tab part, so I didn't need that whole method (as you can see it was commented out in my code anyways).

So I would like to affirm again, that the [TabWidget current tab bottom line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color?lq=1) did mostly work for me, even though downloading the drawables from Github took forever, because you have to download the entire parent folder... but I did, then picked out the ones I needed, placed them in the right folder and it worked! Also note that you have to put the tab indicator xml (given in the answer) into your drawable folder, as this is the convention whenever an xml has `<selector>` tags.