# Any easy way to change Android Action Bar "selected" color?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-theme, android-tabs, android-styles

I'm able to change a lot of colors through using the Android style documentation from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) and looking at the source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml).

Using what I learned above, I was able to change the ActionBar.TabBar, ActionBar.TabText, and ActionBar.TabView, but I don't know what that little highlight is called. Searching for a holo blue in the android source code from above also didn't help.

I still don't know if there is any way in styles.xml to specify that "blue" highlight color to be changed.

[image]

---

### EDIT:

I know that I can use the the action bar style generator, but I'm looking at if I can set the color of it in code (whether it be java or xml). I would not like to have to generate a new drawable for this purpose.

Comment: You might have to create your own theme

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way You can have is to use [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) to easily theme your action bar and tabs.

You can also refer [ActionBar Documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for a customized `ActionBar`.Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
</style>

<!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_background</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_split_background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Alternatively you can try [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).There is one sample available in the library named "Style ActionBar".Using this you can change ActionBar tabs underline color.

I also see a useful link in a comment to your question.You are good to go after referring all these links.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But you change it to a background that includes two colors. The actual background color and the highlight color... no?