# ActionBar AppCompat change Tab indicator color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I have seen many posts and answers but still not clear to me, what to do if i have **to change Tab indicator color** without using `Android Asset Studio`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements           android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener{

private ViewPager tabsviewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabsviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabspager);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    tabsviewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));        
    //getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg));
    getSupportActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));


    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab friendstab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_action_account_child).setTabListener(this);
    Tab publicprofiletab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_action_account_box).setTabListener(this);
    Tab communitytab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_action_account_circle).setTabListener(this);

    getSupportActionBar().addTab(friendstab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(publicprofiletab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(communitytab);
```

I have attached existing app screenshot, how my action bar currently looking, see below:

[image]

As you can see, i am using `#0000ff` for Action bar `background`, and same color i want to use for `Tab Indicator`

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`actionBarTabStyle` attribute should be with the base Application/Activity theme , not under `ActionBar` style

**see create new style for your application and apply to  node in manifest file.**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabViewStyle</item>
<item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabView</item>
```

**custom ActionBarTab theme like this**

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabView">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_stacked_background</item>
```

and **@style/MyActionBarTabView** this is simpler one android style.

also refer [Styling ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: This changes the entire tab's background. How do you change the indicator's color only?

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector for the tabs and add presses state with drawables like:

```
<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
```

For detailed answer and copyright links see this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14722654/3879470).