# Change support ActionBar tabs indicator color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

This is a follow up question to this question:

[ActionBar AppCompat change Tab indicator color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394531/actionbar-appcompat-change-tab-indicator-color)

I'm using the support action bar and adding tabs to it. I want to change the indicator color. What I've tried doing is this:

```
 <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabViewStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabViewStyle</item>
    </style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/White</item>
    </style>
```

This changes the entire tab's color, but I want to change the indicator's color only. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not using a tab layout. I'm using the action bar tabs

Comment: Hey Please Look this, https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActionBar-Tabs-with-Fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create the theme for the app, the action bar, and the tabs. We need
   to set the background for the tabs to the `“tab_bar_background”`
   drawable.

   in **res/values/styles.xml**

   ```
   <style name="FindMyTrain" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
       <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/FindMyTrain.ActionBar.Tab</item>
       <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/FindMyTrain.ActionBar.Tab</item>
   </style>

   <style name="FindMyTrain.ActionBar.Tab">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. in **res/drawable/tab_bar_background** add a color state list

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <selector
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   <item
   android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
   android:state_pressed="false"
   android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>   <item
   android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
   android:state_pressed="false"
   android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected"/>   <item
   android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@color/tab_highlight"/>   <item
   android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected_pressed"/>
   </selector>
   ```

   here you can customize tab bar pressed and selected state color.
3. in **res/drawable/tab_bar_background_selected**

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <stroke android:color="#ff4ba587" android:width="5dp"/>
               </shape>
           </item> </layer-list>
   ```
4. Now apply the theme:

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/FindMyTrain"
       android:name=".FindMyTrainApplication" >
   ```

Output:

[image]

For detail documentation see this [Link](https://blog.alwold.com/2013/08/28/styling-tabs-in-the-android-action-bar/)

Comment: It worked. Whats the secret here? How does the background attribute now change the indicator color only and not the entire background of the tab?

Comment: it's because of the styles and parent attribute..`"@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`..chooses the whole background

Comment: but I didn't change the parent.. I took the exact style as it was (the same one written in my question) and just changed the background attribute in "MyActionBarTabViewStyle" to the selector you wrote

Comment: okay ...i actually didn;t test the code..but i think it's because of `tab_bar_background_selected`..where is a rectangle shape defined with stroke color at bottom which is called each time a action bar tab is selected

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this to change your indicator color.**

```
TabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int color)
```

Comment: I am not using a tab layout. I'm using the action bar tabs