# TabWidget change tab bottom line color

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I would like to change "Tab bottom line color" i followed this steps:
1. on my `styles.xml` file i have:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Dgrey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Dgrey" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_dgrey</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

2. on my `tab_indicator_ab_dgrey` i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_dgrey" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_dgrey" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_dgrey" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_dgrey" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_dgrey" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_dgrey" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_dgrey" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_dgrey" />
</selector>
```

3. in my drawable folders (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) i have these files:
- tab_selected_dgrey.9.png
- tab_selected_focused_dgrey.9.png
- tab_selected_pressed_dgrey.9.png
- tab_unselected_dgrey.9.png
- tab_unselected_focused_dgrey.9.png
- tab_unselected_pressed_dgrey.9.png
and in my drawable folder i have:
`tab_indicator_ab_dgrey.xml` file

4. and at the end, this is my `manifest.xml`:

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="ch.studentgrades.StudentGrades"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```

I don't know why (i followed the tutorial) when i run the app doesn't change anything, the tab line color remain blue.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color) solved my problem.

Add this code after you setup your tabs :

```
TabHost host = (TabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
TabWidget widget = host.getTabWidget();
for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = widget.getChildAt(i);

    // Look for the title view to ensure this is an indicator and not a divider.
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if(tv == null) {
        continue;
    }
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_ab_dgrey);
}
```

Then you can remove the following code from your `styles.xml` :

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Dgrey</item>
```

and

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Dgrey" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_dgrey</item>
</style>
```