# How can I change selected tab bottom line color

Tags: android, android-tabs, tabwidget

I have a TabWidget.
How can I change the bottom line color of the currently selected tab which is defaulted to blue at the moment?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color) answer but it does not say how to change the color...

My layout/main.xml is code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check [this][1] thread. It will help hopefully.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color

Comment: I tried this solution but my app did not work:(

Comment: Try [this](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html) tutorial, all you have to do is to change the color of <color name="tabsScrollColor">#004D40</color> to the color you want :D