# Android Button change style on click

Tags: android

How create buttons with underline light when is clicked.

like tabs but i need only for buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checkout these tutorial.You can use [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: Ya beat me to it. I also by accidently posted the wrong URL

Comment: LOL. Better luck next time @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom `Selector` (similar to `Tabs` Selector) as background to your `Button`.

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:background="@drawable/button_background"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="My button" />
```

Your `button_background.xml` :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

- [tab_unselected_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_holo.9.png) [image: tab_unselected_holo]
- [tab_selected_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_selected_holo.9.png) [image: tab_selected_holo]
- [tab_unselected_focused_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_focused_holo.9.png) [image: tab_unselected_focused_holo]
- [tab_selected_focused_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_selected_focused_holo.9.png) [image: tab_selected_focused_holo]
- [tab_unselected_pressed_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png) [image: tab_unselected_pressed_holo]
- [tab_selected_pressed_holo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_selected_pressed_holo.9.png) [image: tab_selected_pressed_holo]

PS: I get this example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15750561/4224337).