# How to change every tab indicator different Color?

Tags: android, tabs, background-color, android-tabs

I am working on Android app that have 6 tabs and I want each tab indicator to have a different color 
I am using styling System but cant change all tab indicators back
I want something like this

[image: this is from the web]

Please note that I'm using this code for tabs in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "tab1","tab2","tab3","tab4","tab5","tab6" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        


        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }
        for (int i=0;i<=actionBar.getTabCount();i++)
        {

        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color

Comment: @Apurva i use actionbar tab insted of tabhost