# Changing tab selector color (tab underline) for app

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

Screenshot of my app:

[image]

I want to change the blue underline to white programmatically, that is by using java code not using xml styles. Can anyone suggest please how to do it?

Here is my java code. I am able to change tab background.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;


    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Music", "Video"};

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DF0174")));
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DF3A01")));//to change the tab colors


        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }


        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color

Comment: I am not using tabhosts

Comment: You should really really use TabLayout from Android Design Library...

Comment: Is this the only way? Is it not possible to change it just by java code?

Comment: Nope. Its really bad habit to use deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a filter
This will be applied to the region that isn't transparent

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

One line of code - no need to change states

Answer (score 0):

Just add this attribute to your TabLayout in your xml file:

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/yourColor"
```