# It is possible change color of selection in TabHost?

Tags: java, android, tabs, host

Is it possible change a selection color in tabhost?
This is an example:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: please write the code with the implementation of the tabs, so I can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TabWidget current tab bottom line color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color)

Comment: ok thanks! i resolve my problem!