# How to change the color settings of tabs and leave default Ripple like animation?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-tabs

When I create tabs using FragmentTabHost it created tabs with white bachground and yellow indicator below selected tab. When I click on any tab there is an animation that looks like a yellow wave spreading around the surface of a selected tab. Unselected tab's text is gray, while selected tab's text becomes black.

tabs:

[image]

Since tab is clicked:

[image]

I would like to save this animation but only change the colors because its hard to see where the borders star/end and take out the yellow bottom indicator. How can I do that?

I have tried code below and using styles, but all of the material I have found canceled the animation too.

```
for (int i=0; i<mFragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
                mFragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7392B5"));
            }
            mFragmentTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(mFragmentTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4E4E9C"));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I was looking for. It makes animation when pressed disabled

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your colorPrimary/colorSecondary values in the file res/values/color.xml ?

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#f44336</color>
        <color name="colorSecondary">#2f76b6</color>
    </resources>
```

Comment: I think it does depend on these color names. At least I have colorPrimary already specified and it does not match with the one in screenshot