# Android: Use different views for tabs andicator states

Tags: android, view, tabs, state

When I use views as tabSpec indicator the view is the same when a tab is selected or not.

Is there any way to use different views like when we use different drawable (selector) for the selected tab?

I already tried using the selector but it only allow to change the icon. What I want is the use a custom view and still be able to use different views for the different tab states.

Here is my code:

```
View profilInd = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabs_profil_layout, null);
Intent profilIntent = new Intent(this, MyProfilActivity.class);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("profil").setIndicator(profilInd).setContent(profilIntent));
```

The tabs_profil_layout layout is a simple LinearLayout with an ImageView and a TextView.

Comment: [This answer contains example for both states, check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6992662/593709)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use a selector in your view/drawable which will change between the selected and not selected states.

This question covers some similar topics: [Android : Customizing tabs on state : How do I make a selector a drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773690/android-customizing-tabs-on-state-how-do-i-make-a-selector-a-drawable)

Essentially you will be making a drawable resource that looks something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Which you will then assign to the tab.

You can learn more about selectors and Drawable [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: Hi, thinks for your answer.
what I finally did is this:
- I created a selctor with two background png files.
- I created a view that I used as a tab indicator (the java code above didn't change). Within this view I have a LinearLayout that uses the selector as a background.