# How do I programmatically set the TabHost selected and unselected icons?

Tags: android

I have seen multiple examples on how to set the Selected and Unselected icon of a TabHost like this SO question here: [How to change the Tabs Images in the TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507718/how-to-change-the-tabs-images-in-the-tabhost-in-android)

However, I do not want to use the XML file.  I would like to know how to set these icons programmatically.

Any ideas??

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881/updating-android-tab-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [blogged](http://randomencoding.tumblr.com/post/35710334936/android-programmatically-setting-up-selector-drawables) about this recently, but the gist is you need to use `StateListDrawable` class.  It allows you to create multiple different drawables and associate them with specific states (such as when your tab is selected).

Assuming you have two icons in your resources, `icon` and `iconselect`, you would set up the `StateListDrawable` like this:

```
Drawable selectedIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconselect);
Drawable defaultIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
selector.addState(new int[0], defaultIcon);
selector.addState(new int[] { R.attribute.state_selected }, selectedIcon);
```

Notice that for the default (unselected) icon, you pass in an empty array to `addState`.  For the selected icon, you pass in `R.attribute.state_selected` as the state to correlate with the specified icon.  Now you can use this combo drawable when setting up your tab:

```
getTabHost().newTabSpec("tab").setIndicator("Tab 1", selector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example of how to fully customize tabs in a TabHost.  I used this for my app, and had complete control over everything.  The link shows how to do it with XML, but you should be able to convert it over to set the backgrounds, etc. in code:

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately, it does not clearly show how to programmatically set the selected and unselected icon states.  The linked question in my question shows this same method of using XML.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible (or there is no easier ways to achieve this except of specified question).

Comment: Do you have any documentation to support this?

Comment: I tried to do this for a long time, but I have not found any easy way. If it is possible, it will be not so hard to find, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically change image of `TabHost` selected and unselected icons

```
ImageView image= (ImageView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabPosition).findViewById(android.R.id.icon);

image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more_vert_white_24dp);
```